# How can i display images properly in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image

In my application, I have 3 images but they are not shown correct result. I need to display 3 images into single vertically i tried code

```
   using (Bitmap FinalBitmap = new Bitmap(Math.Max(img3.Width, Math.Max(img1.Width, img2.Width)),img1.Height + img2.Height + img3.Height))
 {
                using (Graphics FinalImage = Graphics.FromImage(FinalBitmap))
                {
                    // Draw the first image staring at point (0,0) with actual width and height of the image, in final image
                     FinalImage.DrawImage(img1, new Rectangle(0, 0, img1.Width, img1.Height));                 
                    // and Draw the second image staring at point where first image ends in the final image and save changes
                     FinalImage.DrawImage(img2, 0, img1.Height);                 
                     FinalImage.DrawImage(img3,  0,img2.Height);

                    FinalImage.Save();


                }
        }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rectangle you create need to be the height off all the images. Img1.Height+img2.Height+img3.height

When you draw the last image you need to start at the point of img1.height+img2.height

Comment: Did you try to add the height of img1 and img2 when you draw the last image? FinalImage.DrawImage(img3,  0,img2.Height + img1.Height);